# Map IP to hostname in linux

Tags: linux

Is there any file in linux where IP can be mapped to hostname.Please tell me the path

As we have in windows: By changing in host file we can map a static ip to a host name.

Comment: You mean to say even if answers are not correct i have to accept them to mislead people?

Comment: Not at all. Like I said, mark as accepted any _correct_ answers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you mean the [/etc/hosts file](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap9sec95.html)?

```
/etc/hosts
```

Typical entries might look like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1 sagan
192.168.1.87 bohr
```

Comment: what if make 192.168.1.87 to sagan(in your case). Will this work... as 127.0.0.1 is loopback address.